# Optimise slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

Consider the following MySQL statement

```
SELECT AccountNumber, Currency, Balance 
FROM clients 
    JOIN balances ON clients.AccountNumber= balances.AccountNumber  
WHERE date > “2009-01-01”
```

The query runs slowly, please describe what you would do in attempt to resolve this.

Comment: What are your indexes and data volumes?

Comment: Please show CREATE TABLE... for your tables.

Comment: Slow and fast for you is what time ?

Comment: `balances` needs an index on `AccountNumber` and another index on `date` (assuming that `date` is *not* a field of a `clients` table; it makes more sense on the `balances`, but there's no way to tell for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.AccountNumber, C.Currency, B.Balance FROM clients C INNER JOIN balances B ON C.AccountNumber=B.AccountNumber WHERE C.date > “2009-01-01”
```

(I assumes: Balance field from table Balances)

Answer (score 0):

Use an index on date column

```
create index yourIndex on yourTable (date DESC);
```

Comment: see dasblinkenlight's comment !!

Comment: Suppose the application was only released three years and so all the records have a date greater than 1st January 2009.  Now what use would an index be?

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index on date is good for starters. This assumes MySql supports clustered indices (Sybase/Sql server do).